# How to call any method or property from user input

Tags: php

I'm using this php library

[fzaninotto/Faker](https://github.com/fzaninotto/Faker)

```
        <?php
         // require the Faker autoloader
         require_once '/path/to/Faker/src/autoload.php';
        // use the factory to create a Faker\Generator instance
        $faker = Faker\Factory::create();
        $name=$_POST['name'];
         switch ($name) {
        case 'text':
               echo $faker->text;
            break;
           case 'name':
               echo $faker->name;
            break;
           case 'address':
                echo $faker->address;
            break;

        default:
             echo $faker->anything;
            break;
    }
     ?>
```

AS You can see to call any method or property of "faker"
I need to use switch statement .
Is there any better way to do things??

```
<form action="index.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="name" value="text" /><br><br>
<input type="submit" value="Run" />
</form>
```

What i want to do is something like this

```
<?php
$name=$_POST['name'];
echo $faker->$name;
//So if user type text
echo $faker->text ; 
//or if user type "words($nb = 3, $asText = false)"
echo $faker->words($nb = 3, $asText = false);
?>
```

Comment: You can do what you are suggesting how ever the parameter one (`$faker->words()`), you would need to extra logic otherwise use braces: `echo $faker->{$name};` if `$name` was equal to `address` then you would be doing the equivalent `echo $faker->address;`

Comment: "you would need to extra logic otherwise use braces". How can i extra login ?? please help if you have any  idea in your mind

Comment: Well sort of what you said, the user would type something like `words|{"nb":"3","text":"false"}` then you could search for `|` using `strpos()`, then  `explode()` the string using `|` then parse the second variable as json and the first as the braced value.

Comment: Also probably use `call_user_func()` / `call_user_func_array()`

Comment: Thanks for suggestion.

Comment: $userinput='words|{"nb":"5","text":"false"}';
  $explode=explode('|',$userinput);
  $functionName=$explode[0];
  $arg=json_decode(end($explode),true);
  echo  call_user_func_array(array($faker, $functionName), $arg);

Comment: It's working thank you so much you can post it as answer of my question

Comment: You can post the answer to your own question, I just gave you some ideas, you actually did it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
    $userinput='paragraph|{"nb":"10","text":"true"}';
        $explode=explode('|',$userinput);
        $functionName=$explode[0];
        $arg=json_decode(end($explode),true);
        echo  call_user_func_array(array($this->faker, $functionName), $arg);
?>
```